# Mobile to controller secure bluetooth ble communication

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

We seek your help in implementing bluetooth on our smart home controller. Our current scenarios is described below:

1. We want secure communication between our embedded linux controller(our smart home hub) and user's mobile phones running android/iOS.Our system is in home automation.
2. The hub in turn communicates with home devices that support a different protocol - we need to make communication between hub and mobile devices using bluetooth.
3. Currently there is not direct communication between our hub and mobile phone except through the internet.
4. We will use Bluetooth 4.x, not 5 for hardware support on the controller.
5. We are using nodejs on our controller and standard bluethooth OS libraries on android/iOS. We are open to suggestions.

Our main concern is to establish secure communication between phone and the hub. With this regard we are looking for implementation guidance on pairing  and communicating securely. We have been able to establish unsecure communication - exposing characteristics and services on the hub. Our understanding of the bluetooth protocol is limited and we have only used libraries available for users.
Please provide specific pointers as to what we should do and what is possible.

Comment: Is your intention to use standard Bluetooth low energy pairing/encryption or some custom protocol?

Comment: Is there a way to pair securely with standard BLE pairing? 9

Comment: Sure. Just read the Bluetooth core standard, the chapter about SMP and you will get all details.